# Keywords (or reserved words) in Julia 1.0

Tags: julia

How do I get keyword information for the version of Julia being run?

For example, there are 33 keywords in Python 3.6, but only 31 in 2.7:

```
# This is Python 3.6 code running in a file:
import keyword
print(len(keyword.kwlist))
## Output: 33

# This is Python 2.7 code running in a file:
import keyword
print len(keyword.kwlist)
## Output: 31
```

Can this kind of check be done in Julia?  Or does someone have a different suggestion for getting info on Julia keywords for the running version?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to responses below I have gotten some interesting suggestions.  However, something seems to be missing.  For example, in each list of reserved words provided below, the word `elseif` is missing.  Am I to believe that `elseif` is not a keyword (or reserved word)?

Also when I go to the Scheme code where `intial-reserved-words` and `reserved-words` come from, I find the following code:

```
(define initial-reserved-words '(begin while if for try return break continue
                         function macro quote let local global const do
                         struct
                         module baremodule using import export))

(define initial-reserved-word? (Set initial-reserved-words))

(define reserved-words (append initial-reserved-words '(end else catch finally true false))) ;; todo: make this more complete
```

At the end of the last line above is the comment:

```
;; todo: make this more complete
```

This seems to imply that even the union of `intial-reserved-words` and the `reserved-words` lists (or whatever they are called in Scheme) is not complete.

Thus, I have held off on checking one of the answers.  I will be happy to check one when I see how to get a canonical list of Julia reserved words in Julia code.  If a Julia expert believes one of the suggestions below is the best way to get the list of keywords (reserved words) for the current version of Julia, I would appreciate knowing it.

Comment: Isn't this a pure Julia question? How is Python related here?

Comment: I wanted to illustrate how keywords can change from version to version of a language.  I am coming from a Python background and wanted to illustrate the kind of thing I am looking for in Julia with actual code in Python.  Also the number of people who know Python and Julia is probably more than the number of people who know only Julia.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but you might find this hack interesting: `mapreduce(α -> Base.REPLCompletions.completions(string(α), 1)[1], vcat,String(Char(0x20):Char(0x7e)))`.

Comment: Interesting hack, but the only Base.REPL... that I get at the Julia 1.0.0 REPL is Base.REPL_MODULE_REF.  Maybe I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: Ahhh, yeah.  I'm still on v0.6.4.  For v1.0.0 I think it might be `mapreduce(α -> Base.REPL_MODULE_REF.x.REPLCompletions.completions(string(α), 1)[1], vcat,String(Char(0x20):Char(0x7e)))`.

Comment: Yes, that provides 29574-element Array{REPL.REPLCompletions.Completion,1}.  Maybe the keywords (reserved words) could be filtered out of that array?

Comment: I bet there's an easier way, but I thought the `completions` provided some interesting insight into what Julia sees inside itself.  :)

Answer (score 9):

Not actually in Julia, but maybe what you are looking for. On the command line, typing `julia --lisp` will bring you to the Lisp interpreter that Julia uses for parsing, in which you can see the list of reversed words by evaluating `reserved-words` (and a lot of others like `operators`).

```
> julia --lisp
;  _
; |_ _ _ |_ _ |  . _ _
; | (-||||_(_)|__|_)|_)
;-------------------|----------------------------------------------------------

> reserved-words
(begin while if for try return break continue function macro quote let local
 global const do struct type immutable importall module baremodule using import
 export end else catch finally true false)
```

Comment: This is cool to know.  However, I was hoping for a way to do this in simple Julia code.  Maybe that is just not possible, in which case your suggestion may be the best available.  I am waiting to see.

Answer (score 7):

Allo,

There are some keywords, you can find them on the [Julia documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Keywords-1).

- If you look at the [Julia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia) repository on github, there's a value [`initial-reserved-words`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/02aa9bbc258a380b5c9fbe2f2d3276a90a72abca/src/julia-parser.scm#L150) containing all keywords. You can access it from the command line:

```
$ julia --lisp
;  _
; |_ _ _ |_ _ |  . _ _
; | (-||||_(_)|__|_)|_)
;-------------------|-------------------------------------------------------

> initial-reserved-words
(begin while if for try return break continue function macro quote let local
 global const do struct module baremodule using import export)
```

- Or you can create an array yourself:

```
keywords = ("begin","while","if","for","try","return","break","continue","function","macro",
            "quote","let","local","global","const","do","struct","module","baremodule",
            "using","import","export")

print(length(keywords)) # 22
```

If you are new to Julia, I recommend you take a look at:

- [Learn Julia in Y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/julia/)

It's a bunch of example so you can experiment on the language.
I hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for the links.  Yes, the Julia 1.0 documentation does identify keywords.  For example, return is listed as a keyword.  However, I would like to get the list of keywords programmatically, as in the Python 2.7/3.6 examples.

Comment: The initial-reserved-words value appears to be in a Scheme file.  I do not know Scheme and do not know how to access it from Julia.  Also, the word initial troubles me. Does that mean there are more after the initial values are set?

Comment: You could get them from the julia console I believe, otherwise the only way I know would be to create the array yourself.

Comment: How would you get them from the Julia console?

Comment: try pressing tab two times it should appear, or you could use the help `-h` or with `?` command

Comment: Pressing tab two times provides me with a large list of words, but I do not think they are all keywords.  For example, pi is one of the words that is listed.

Comment: Then the workaround would be to create your own array of keyword.

Comment: Then I would need a canonical listing.  I am not sure if the initial-reserved-words is it.  Anyway, thanks for the effort you have put into this question.  I now suspect that getting the keywords in Julia code may not yet be available.

Comment: But how can you be sure your keyword list is complete?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180081/discussion-between-sylhare-and-julialearner).

Comment: Okay, but I have to leave my laptop at this time.